# scala class generated with Avrohugger failed when primary constructors provided to the case class is more than 254 columns

Tags: java, scala, avro, case-class, avrohugger

We are using Avrohugger tool to generate the scala class file from the Avro schema. But the scala class files fails during compilation with "JVM Spec Violation 255 Parameter Limit Exceeded".

I have tried multiple options to remediate this but still no solution.

One approach is to add the remaining primary constructors(256 (total number of columns) - 254(allowable columns)) as fields inside the case class. When I am trying to access the fields inside the case class, I am getting another error as 
 "unknown parameter name XXX `enter code here`" (XXX is the filed that is defined inside the case class)
 "256 arguments but expected 254 arguments"
 (this is because I have placed 254 parameters as primary constructors and 2 additional parameters as values inside the case class).

How can I over over this issue using Avrohugger.

I have create the scala Schema files and edited the scala file but it is failing while retrieving the additional columns that are defined inside th body of the case class.

the modified files looks like this:

```
case class Apple(col1, col2, .... col254) extends 
org.apache.avro.specificRecordBase with ParsedData{

var col255 = None: Option[String]
var col256 = None: Option[String]

def this() = this(None, .......None) // count is 254

def get ( ) ....   // i have included all the 256 col
def put () ....     // i have included all the 256 col

def getSchema(): org.apache.avro.Schema =  A.schema

}

object Apple{

val SCHEMA = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parse( <schema definition>) // all 
the 256 columns

   }
```

This schema is used in the code as :

```
object Job extends App {

Apple(
 col1 = "1",
 col2 - None,
 ..
col254 = "Hello"
col255 = "Something"
col257 = "Something Else"
)
```

}

Comment: It is a tough situation, the 255 limit comes not from Scala, it comes from the JVM (implied by the "byte" term in the "byte-code"). Working with such a huge types will be problematic in different parts. Be prepared that there might be no good solutions for your problem.

Comment: So are you saying that we need to stop using Avohugger to generate the arvo schema and follow a different approach. If so please suggest another approach. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I meant. Taking it literally I said you should give up on either using such incredibly long records or JVM. I understand that most probably both solutions are not feasible for you. Your case is an extreme corner case and it easily might be that non of the available libraries handles it well. That's why you must be ready that there is no good available solution at all. I know this is bad news but this is what the life sometimes is. Ultimately you might have to roll out a custom solution. Still there is a change that someone else here knows a good solution.